# Laravel 5.4 - failed to group data based on user request

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to create a report whose data can be grouped and ordered based on user requests

I have three tables

```
// items
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+
| id |    name    | category_id | location_id |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+
|  9 | Mouse 3    |           3 |           3 |
|  8 | Keyboard 3 |           2 |           3 |
|  7 | Monitor 3  |           1 |           3 |
|  6 | Mouse 2    |           3 |           2 |
|  5 | Keyboard 2 |           2 |           2 |
|  4 | Monitor 2  |           1 |           2 |
|  3 | Mouse 1    |           3 |           1 |
|  2 | Keyboard 1 |           2 |           1 |
|  1 | Monitor 1  |           1 |           1 |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+

// item_categories
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  3 | Mouse    |
|  2 | Keyboard |
|  1 | Monitor  |
+----+----------+

// item_locations
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  3 | Room 3 |
|  2 | Room 2 |
|  1 | Room 1 |
+----+--------+
```

**items.blade.php**

```
<div class="input-field">
<select name="groupBy">
    <option value="not grouped">Not Grouped - Default</option>
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="category_id {{ $category->id }}">Category: {{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
    @foreach ($locations as $location)
        <option value="location_id {{ $location->id }}">Location: {{ $location->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<label>Group by</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field">
<select name="orderBy">
    <option value="id asc">Id (Asc) - Default</option>
    <option value="id desc">Id (Desc)</option>
    <option value="name asc">Name (A - Z)</option>
     <option value="name desc">Name (Z - A)</option>
    <option value="updated_at desc">Date (Newest)</option>
    <option value="updated_at asc">Date (Oldest)</option>
</select>
<label>Order by</label>
</div>
```

**ItemController**

```
public function create()
{
    $items = Item::Join('item_categories', 'items.category_id', '=', 'item_categories.id')
                 ->Join('item_locations', 'items.location_id', '=', 'item_locations.id')
                 ->select('items.*', 'item_categories.name as category_name', 'item_locations.name as location_name')
                 ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                 ->get();

    $categories = ItemCategories::all();
    $locations = ItemLocation::all();

    return view('menu.items', compact('items', 'categories', 'locations'));
}
```

**ReportController**

```
public function items(Request $request)
{
$date = Carbon::now()->toFormattedDateString();

$orderByArray = explode(' ', request('orderBy'));
$orderColumn = $orderByArray[0];
$orderDirection = $orderByArray[1];

$groupByArray = explode(' ', request('groupBy'));
$groupColumn = $groupByArray[0];
$groupDirection = $groupByArray[1];

if (request('groupBy') == 'not grouped') {
  $items = Item::Join('item_categories', 'items.category_id', '=', 'item_categories.id')
               ->Join('item_locations', 'items.location_id', '=', 'item_locations.id')
               ->select('items.*', 'item_categories.name as category_name', 'item_locations.name as location_name')
               ->orderBy($orderColumn, $orderDirection)
               ->get();
} else {
  $items = Item::Join('item_categories', 'items.category_id', '=', 'item_categories.id')
               ->Join('item_locations', 'items.location_id', '=', 'item_locations.id')
               ->select('items.*', 'item_categories.name as category_name', 'item_locations.name as location_name')
               ->orderBy($orderColumn, $orderDirection)
               ->groupBy($groupColumn)
               ->having($groupColumn, '=', $groupDirection)
               ->get();
}

return $items;
```

}

I try to group by not grouped and ordered by all options and it works well, all data ordered by user request

but when I try to group by category: monitor and order by id (asc) and id (desc) appear only last data entered by user with category id = 1 which is id for monitor category as I showed below

```
[
{
    "id": 7,
    "category_id": "1",
    "location_id": "3",
    "name": "Monitor 3",
    "quantity": "0",
    "created_at": "2018-02-11 06:40:08",
    "updated_at": "2018-02-11 06:40:08",
    "category_name": "Monitor",
    "location_name": "Room 3"
}
]
```

it also happens if I group by other options and order by other options as well, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to this: `->select('items.*', 'item_categories.name as category_name', 'item_locations.name as location_name', 'items.location_id as location_id', 'items.category_id as category_id')` you need to include those 2 fields because you are grouping by one of them, so this way it will work with both sent `location_id` or `category_id`